# Ball on a rotating beam - equations of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

i am trying to model a ball in a rotating beam using lagrangian mechanics. The model is presented in the following image:

[image]

I know the equations of motions are:

$$ 
\left[ \frac{J_b}{r^2} + m \right]\ddot{p}(t) + mgsin(\theta) - mp(t)\dot{\theta}(t)^2 = 0
\label{eq1}
$$

$$ 
\left[ mp(t)^2 + J + J_b \right]\ddot{\theta}(t) + 2mp(t)\dot{p}(t)\dot{\theta}(t) + mgp(t)cos(\theta)  = \tau(t)
\label{eq2}
$$

I am writing the lagrangian as: L = T-V, where T is the kinetic energy and V is the potential energy.

$$
T = \underbrace{ \frac{1}{2}m_b\dot{p}(t)^2 }_{kinetic \ energy \ of \ ball} + \underbrace{ \frac{1}{2}(\frac{J_b}{r^2})\dot{p}(t)^2 }_{rotational \ energy \ of \ ball \ around \ it's \ axis}  + \underbrace{ \frac{1}{2}J\dot{\theta}(t)^2 }_{rotational\ energy \ of \ beam}  + \underbrace{ \frac{1}{2}( m_b\cdot p(t)^2 )\dot{\theta}(t)^2  }_{rotational\ energy \ of \ ball \ around \ beam's \ axis} 
$$

$$
V = m_bgh = m_bg(\  p(t)\cdot sin(\theta) \ ) 
$$

and then i am finding the lagrangian as:
$$ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}  =  Q_{ext}
$$

Where $Q_{ext}= \tau (t)$.

However, i am missing the $J_b$ term in the second equation. That is to say, the coeffiecient of $\ddot{\theta}$ is $\left[ mp(t)^2 + J \right]$. What energy term have i forgotten?

Comment: It seems you forgot to square p(t) in the rotational energy of the ball around the center. Or not?

Comment: @Felicia Indeed i had forgotten to square $p(t)$ in the question, but it i had squared it in my calculations.  It does't impact the missing $J_b$.

Comment: Is the missing Jb what comes to be after inserting your L in the equation?

Comment: I am a bit surprised by the model. When I tried to recreate it, I got something with more terms. As if in this model, the radius of the rolling ball has been set to zero, except in that term $J_b / r^2$ and implicitly in the moment of inertia $J_b$. Is this supposed to be a simplified model? Is this from a textbook? BTW Opeth are GREAT :D!

Comment: I took a picture from a powerpoint in a control class and searched on-line to find a solution. But i did not find one available. So, this is a picture of the same problem i found online. I think the simplifications are that it treats the bodies as rigid and there is no friction. And yeah, opeth are great :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss one term for the energy. The ball makes more rotation than only because of its rolling along the beam. For example, if the ball is stuck to the bead, it rotates ine time if the beam rotates once.

Comment: You are right. When i examined the rolling of the ball i considered it a solid body, but then I considered the ball as a point mass when i checked the rotation of the beam. Thanks a lot